# How to get the Index Size in Solr using Java

Tags: java, solr

I need to get total size of an index in Apache Solr using Java. The following code gets the total number of documents but I am looking for the size. And with the use of ReplicationHandler I was thinking that I can get the index size as told by someone here on this link.. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/cheking-the-size-of-the-index-using-solrj-API-s-td692686.html but I am not getting the index size.

```
BufferedWriter out1 = null;
        FileWriter fstream1 = new FileWriter("src/test/resources/solr-document-id-desc.txt");
        out1 = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);
        ApplicationContext context = null;
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        CommonsHttpSolrServer solrServer = (CommonsHttpSolrServer) context.getBean("solrServer");
        SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery().setQuery("*:*");

      QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.query(solrQuery);

        //I am trying to use replicationhandler but I am not able to get the index size using statistics. Is there any way to get the index size..?                        
       ReplicationHandler handler2 = new ReplicationHandler();
       System.out.println( handler2.getDescription()); 

       NamedList statistics = handler2.getStatistics();
       System.out.println("Statistics   "+ statistics); 
       System.out.println(rsp.getResults().getNumFound());

      Iterator<SolrDocument> iter = rsp.getResults().iterator();

      while (iter.hasNext()) {
                      SolrDocument resultDoc = iter.next();        
                      System.out.println(resultDoc.getFieldNames());
                      String id = (String) resultDoc.getFieldValue("numFound");
                      String description = (String) resultDoc.getFieldValue("description");
                      System.out.println(id+"~~"+description);
                      out1.write(id+"~~"+description);
                      out1.newLine();
      }
      out1.close();

    Any suggestions will be appreciated..
```

**Update Code:-**

```
ReplicationHandler handler2 = new ReplicationHandler();
System.out.println( handler2.getDescription()); 
 NamedList statistics = handler2.getStatistics();
 System.out.println("Statistics   "+ statistics.get("indexSize"));
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you make your question clearer :) You've presented code, but not said what you're *trying* to do or what it *actually* does, or any problems you've been having. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have updated the questions. let me know if it makes sense now..

Comment: Not really - you say you *have* got the index size, but that you're "not getting" it... so what happens?

Comment: I have got the number of documents in the Solr.. I need the index size..!!

Comment: "And with the use of ReplicationHandler I was thinking that I can get the index size as told by someone here on this link" - and what was the result?

Comment: I am not getting anything. I just want to make sure what I did is right or wrong? How does ReplicationHandler is getting to know about which solr server we are talking about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The indexsize is available with the statistics in [ReplicationHandler](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/solr/solr-3.3.0/org/apache/solr/handler/ReplicationHandler.java.html)

```java
org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler
```

code

```java
  public NamedList getStatistics() {
    NamedList list = super.getStatistics();
    if (core != null) {
      list.add("indexSize", NumberUtils.readableSize(getIndexSize()));
    }
  }
```

You can use the URL `http://localhost:8983/solr/replication?command=details` , which returns the index size.

```xml
<lst name="details">
  <str name="indexSize">26.13 KB</str>
  .....
</lst>
```

Not sure if it works with the instantiation of ReplicationHandler, as it would need the reference of the core and the index.

Comment: how can I use this in my code. I think I have tried doing this in my above code..

Comment: Try statistics.get("indexSize");

Comment: I have updated the code, I am not getting any thing by that..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command in the data directory

```
  - du -kx
```

Comment: OP is asking for a way in Java to do this.

Answer (score 0):

as said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660487/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-solr-document/23962913#23962913) you can use [MAT tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) in order to see the memory consumption. I think that you could use in your code. Enjoy solr!