# How can I get the size of a Solr document?

Tags: solr, solr4j

I would like to know the size in bytes of individual Solr documents/responses.  Is there a straightforward way to figure this out?

We are using the solrj java client.

I've looked around and have only found ways to determine the size of the index, but nothing on the size of the documents themselves.

Comment: What are you looking for as "size"?  Are you asking about the internal representation of the document on Solr's end?

Comment: Yes, or whatever Solr sends over the wire back to the Java client

Comment: Does solrj not let you see the raw JSON/XML/whatever that Solr sends back?

Answer (score 6):

the size and the document of solr are composed of both :
- indexes compressed
- files compressed

A easy way to know the size of you solr core / node is to get in solr admin
[image]

So in my case we have :
2993 document for 5,41 MB = an average of 1,8KB / document including the index / and the stored fields.

There is also another way if you are more geeky and love to code : 
[how to get the Index Size in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934000/how-to-get-the-index-size-in-solr)

**`UPDATE THE 5/06/2014 :`**
Hehe, I've found something that sound good : [ MAT tool[3](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/05/see-your-solr-cache-sizes-eclipse-memory-analyzer.html)
You can lookup the lru cache in order to understand the memory used (and the space used by a specific doc). By running a get of the ID, you will have the ID retrieved and the memory taken by the ID on HDD/RAM! :)

See this great article :

- [MAT usage](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/05/see-your-solr-cache-sizes-eclipse-memory-analyzer.html) ,
- [MAT](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/08/eclipse-memory-analyzer-mat.html) .

Comment: Thanks, but my goal was to determine the size of particular documents, not just an average of all of them.

Comment: unfortunatly, there is only the statistical way to do that. What do you need to perform with this calculation exactly ? What is your use case? thanks

Comment: take a look at my complement of response please!